# Cannot use navigation on component inside arrow function. Undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'n.props.navigation')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Cannot navigate to other screen

I've tried import withNavigation but still can't work, it was showing

> Uncaught Error : Undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'n.props.navigation')

Article.js

```
import ArticleItem from 'ArticleItem'
.....
        <FlatList
          style={styles.containerFlatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
            <ArticleItem
              navigation={this.props.navigation}
              title={item.title}
              image={item.article_path}
              id={item.id}
              date={moment(item.created_at).locale('id').format("ll")}/>
          }
          keyExtractor={({title},index) => title}

        />
      }
```

ArticleItem.js

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import DetailArticle from '../screens/DetailArticle';

import Router from '../Router';

export default ArticleItem = (data) => (
<View style={styles.containerArticle}>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
  {this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailArticle')}}>
  <Image style={styles.imageArticle} source= 
   {{uri:'http://localhost/img/'+data.image}}/>
  <View style={{padding: 10}}>
   <Text style={{marginBottom: 8, fontSize: 18}}>{data.title}</Text>
   <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color:'grey'}}>{data.date}</Text>
  </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
);
```

Did i missed something?

Comment: Hello, Use Double Quotes in your navigation. Instead of {this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailArticle')} do 
{this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailArticle")} hope this helps.

Comment: Just try but still have same error, did need some called props in big arrow function? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it looks like `ArticleItem` is a function component so in that you cannot access props from `this` keyword.

For your example you are sending props as `data`

So access the navigation as `data.navigation.navigate('some-route')`

For a component like this.

```
<ComponentA a='1' b='2'/>
```

If this is a functional component like here

```
const ComponentA=props=>{
 //access here as props.a or props.b
 return someJSX
}
```

Comment: Got it, nice thanks. So does every function component following their props component?
Do you have more refference about this?